# Retrieivng image from DB using multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, multer, mern

I am working on MERN application and I am facing issue in displaying the image.Using multer, the image path store in the MongoDB after file uploaded successfully and the image also stores in the folder "uploads", but there is problem I am getting while retrieving the image path from db.

all the text data retrieved but displaying image give me error.

Error I got:
CANNOT GET http://localhost:3000/uploads/image-1614468761737.jpg

Here is the code.

```
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")
const route = express.Router()
const Post = require("../models/postModel")
const multer = require("multer")

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req,file,cb){
        cb(null,"uploads/")
    },
    filename(req,file,cb){
        cb(null, `${file.fieldname}-${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`)
    }
})

const upload = multer({
    storage,
    filefilter: function(req,file,cb) {
        const filetypes = /jpg|jpeg|png/
        const extname = filetypes.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase())
        const mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype)
        if(extname && mimetype){
            return cb(null, true)
         }else{
             cb(null,false)
         }
    },
})

route.post("/upload",upload.single("image"),(req,res)=>{
    const file = req.file.path.replace(/\\/g,"/" )
    res.send(`/${file}`)
})

route.post("/", async(req,res)=>{
    const post = req.body
    try {
        const createpost = new Post(post)
        await createpost.save()    
        res.status(200).json(createpost)
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404).json({msg:"create post failed"})
    }
})

module.exports = route
```

in the main file I also add

```
app.use("/uploads",express.static(path.join(__dirname,"/uploads")))
```

file structure:
[file structure and uploads folder is in the root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xieQq.png)

GitHub:
https://github.com/mozi47/Check-error